# runat server field not filled when clicking on button?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using an aspx file as my main page with the following code snippet:

```
  <input type="text" runat="server" id="Password" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="SavePassword" 
            Text="Save" OnClick="SavePassword_Click"/>
```

Then in the code behind I use:

```
protected void SavePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = Password.Value.ToString();
}
```

Setting Password.Value in the Page_Load works as expected, but setting a to the value results in  an empty string in a regardless what I type in on the page befoere I click the save button.

Am I overlooking here something?

Comment: Are you perhaps emptying the value of `Password` somewhere? Like in Page_load? If so you need to wrap that in an `IsPostBack` check. Because the above snippet works.

Comment: IsPostback was it tnx. Didn't think that that part could be relevant there (beginners error)

Comment: change `input` to `asp:textbox` or add `name="Password"` to input. currently your `input` is not included into post.

Answer (score 0):

You should add label field with name labelShow in aspx page like this

```
 <asp:Label ID="labelShow" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Then add the string into .cs file

```
protected void SavePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = Password.Value.ToString();
    labelShow.Text = a.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can figure several errors :

- You say something about Page_Load. You should always remember Page_Load is executed at every postback. So if you write something into the textbox at Page_Load, it will erase the value typed by user. You can change this behavior by veriyfing

  `if(!IsPostBack) 
   { 
      // Your code 
   }`

around your Page_Load content.

- `input runat="server"` is not the proper way to do TextBox in ASP.Net, in most cases you should use `asp:TextBox`
- You don't do anything with your "a" string, your current code sample does nothing, whether the Password field is properly posted or not. You can do as suggested by Ravi in his answer to display it.

I suggest you to to learn how to use VS debugger, and to read a good course on ASP.Net Webforms to learn it.